# Convert Nested JSON into Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a nested JSON like below. I want to convert it into a pandas dataframe. As part of that, I also need to parse the weight value only. I don't need the unit.

I also want the number values converted from string to numeric.

Any help would be appreciated. I'm relatively new to python. Thank you.

JSON Example:

```
{'id': '123', 'name': 'joe', 'weight': {'number': '100', 'unit': 'lbs'}, 
'gender': 'male'}
```

Sample output below:

```
id     name    weight    gender
123    joe     100       male
```

Answer (score 1):

use " from pandas.io.json import json_normalize ".

```
id     name    weight.number  weight.unit  gender
123    joe     100              lbs        male
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to discard the weight unit, just flatten the json:

```
temp = {'id': '123', 'name': 'joe', 'weight': {'number': '100', 'unit': 'lbs'}, 'gender': 'male'}
temp['weight'] = temp['weight']['number']
```

then turn it into a dataframe:

```
pd.DataFrame(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
json_data = [{'id': '123', 'name': 'joe', 'weight': {'number': '100', 'unit': 'lbs'}, 'gender': 'male'}]
# convert the data to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(json_data)
# conver id to an int
df['id'] = df['id'].apply(int)
# get the 'number' field of weight and convert it to an int
df['weight'] = df['weight'].apply(lambda x: int(x['number']))
df
```